# How can I pass a value from one page to another in a React app?

Tags: reactjs

I can find people doing this in the old syntax but not with ES6. how do i pass the userId you get from clicking on the username to the userProfile?

here is my userprofile.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../Home/Home.css";
import NavBar from "./../Navbar/Navbar";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const UserProfile = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const userId = state?.userId;
  

  console.log(userId);

  return (
    <div className="Home">
      <NavBar />
      <div>
        <h1>{userId}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserProfile;
```

here is addFreinds.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { QUERY_USER, QUERY_ME } from "../../utils/queries";
import { useLazyQuery, useMutation, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { ADD_FRIEND } from "../../utils/mutations";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";


const AddFriend = ({ username, currentUser, myId }) => {
  const [addFriend] = useMutation(ADD_FRIEND);
  const [getUser, { loading, data, error }] = useLazyQuery(QUERY_USER, {
    variables: { username: username },
  });
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const userId = data?.user?._id;
  const friend2 = currentUser;
  console.log(friend2);

  const handleAddFriendClick = async () => {
    await getUser();
    navigate({
      pathname: `/UserProfile/${userId}`,
      state: { userId: userId },
    });
  };
  

  console.log(userId);
  
  return (
    <>
      <p onClick={handleAddFriendClick}>
        {username}{" "}
        </p>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddFriend;
```

here is my routes

```
function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
          <Route path="/likes" element={<LikesPage />} />
          <Route path="/Search" element={<Search />} />
          <Route path="/UserProfile/:userId" element={<UserProfile />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

Tried a couple things but have not been successful, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a state managment such as react context, redux, recoil etc...

react context is one of the most easiest way in react to get a value from a child component and accessing it inside a parent component or even inside a component in other components tree.

if your project is going to be complex I would recommand using redux for state management.

For more info about react context [click here](https://hu.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
for more info about redux [click here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Good luck

Comment: I've been looking at the documentation and watching videos but am having a hard time incorporating it into my code. Any more help would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the userId in URL, you need to catch it from the path params

You can extract the userId using `useParams` from react-router.

```js
let { userId } = useParams();
```

Check this link for useParams documentation:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams